# Detect if bytes object represent a PDF document in python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a list of bytes objects, that can be either :

- a text (on which I know the encoding)
- a pdf document
- a zip document

If I can't decode the bytes object, using something like:

```
<bytes object>.decode(encoding)
```

clearly it is not a text. This is fine, as I can handle the exception.

But then how can I detect if it is a PDF or a ZIP document ?

Comment: you can always check the first 4 bytes, if they are 50 4b 03 04 then you have a zip file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers

Comment: Look at the first 4 bytes of the file. PDF has "%PDF" (hex 25 50 44 46) and ZIP has hex 50 4B 03 04.